# Problem while updating Ubuntu 20.04 with Synaptic

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, update-manager, synaptic

I try to update Ubuntu 20.04 using Synaptic, but the update generates an error:

```
E: se interrumpió la ejecución de dpkg, debe ejecutar manualmente «dpkg --configure -a» para corregir el problema
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
 
W: No se utilizan bloqueos para el fichero de bloqueo de sólo lectura /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend W: No se utilizan bloqueos para el fichero de bloqueo de sólo lectura /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

I try to fix this error and I get:

```
dpkg: error: unable to access the dpkg database directory /var/lib/dpkg: File System only read
```

By reading several tutorials, I found that I should remove the `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` file, but when I try to remove it using `rm`, I get:

```
rm: does not erase ‘/var/lib/apt/lists/lock’: File System only read
```

Is there any way to fix this error without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: You have a problem in your system that is resulting in the system being locked in read-only mode.  This usually means your system is not clean.  Do you still have the installation media for your Ubuntu?  I ask because we may need to boot to it to run a file system check cleanly on your system.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Yes, although I am afraid of formatting the disk and losing my information

Comment: You restart your pc, Yoy use initrmfs, con option help. fsck -c -y your damage partition

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 1):

Your disk is in read-only mode, which usually means there's something wrong with your file system. Do the following to repair this...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thanks heynnema